# How to change v-model format in PrimeVue calendar selection?

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I´m using the [Calendar](https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/calendar) component of `PrimeVue`. As stated in the documentation, you should be able to set `dateFormat` to "Format of the date". I used it in my `Vue.js` component like:

```
<Calendar 
    :id="fields.data.formName" 
    v-model="catalogEntrySelections[fields.data.formName]"
    dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
    :showIcon="true"
    :showWeek="true"
/>
```

When I select a date, like today the 14. Sept 2021, it show `2021-09-14` in the `input` of the calendar. But in my `v-model` the date shows as `2021-09-13T22:00:00.000Z`. In fact it doens´t matter which format I apply to `dateFormat`, it will always be the same format in the `v-model`.

**Question:** Is there a way by `PrimeVue`, which I´m maybe missing, to set a format for the `v-model`?

Comment: The dateFormat is only for the label. If you want to set format in the v-model you have to set watch on the v-model value.

Comment: @TomekC. Thank you for the comment. Can you provide a small example as an answer to give me the opportunity to accept your answer, if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some watch example:

```
//...
//component code
data() {
    return {
      inputDate:null,
       //other variables
    }
  }, 
 watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    inputDate: function (newValue, oldValue) {
          this.catalogEntrySelections[fields.data.formName] =  
             parseDate(newValue); 
          this.inputDate = newValue; //changing newValue here triggers 
                                    // watch again, which will end in
                                    // cyclic dependecies error
      }
    },
   
//...
//component code
```

and updated template

```
<Calendar 
    :id="fields.data.formName" 
    v-model="inputDate"
    dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
    :showIcon="true"
    :showWeek="true"
/>
```